# Calling a web service method from ASP.NET 1.1 using jQuery ajax, not returning any data.

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have hosted a web service that gets called from an **ASP.NET 1.1** by jQuery ajax.

Here is the code i am using to call the web service :

```
function OnTrimLevelChange() 
{
    var $jDecode = jQuery.noConflict();
    var vin = $jDecode("input[id*=txtVIN]").val();
    var styleId = '';
    var paramList = '{"vin": "' + vin + '","styleID": "' + styleId + '"}';
    try
    {

        $jDecode.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'http://192.168.10.10/VINDecoder/service.asmx/CallADSWebMethod',
            data: paramList,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('I am here');
        },
            error: function(xml,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                alert(xml.status + "||" + xml.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    catch(er)
    {
    }
}
```

=======================================================
The **above** always going to the error part.
**Error: 
xml.status = 0 
xml.responseText = null**

Web method code is :

```
[WebMethod]
public VINDescription CallADSWebMethod(string vin, string styleID)
{
       VehicleDescription vehicleDescription = FetchVehicleInfo(vin, true, styleID);

        VINDescription vinDescription = new VINDescription();

        try
        {
            if (vehicleDescription != null)
            {
                //Check if the response status of the call is successful or not.
                if (vehicleDescription.responseStatus.description.Equals("Successful"))
                {
                    vinDescription = AddToVINDescription(vehicleDescription);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
        }
        return vinDescription;
}
```

Note : The webservice is created in .Net 4.0 and site from which i am calling is in 1.1.
They are hosted in different servers.

PLease let me know what am i lacking here or what mistake i am doing her..

Comment: What is the error you get back? xml.responseText

Comment: xml.status  = 0
xml.responseText = nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script service execution was needed to be enabled in the web service. Like this :

```
[ScriptService]
```